# How can I join and group two tables by a column that may or may not have a known prefix?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with phone numbers, these numbers may or may not have a + prefixed on them. I have to magically join these two tables!

What are my options if I want to avoid doing a nested select clause to concatenate the data with + where necessary?

- Table A has a phone field. Numbers may or may not have a +.
- Table B has a phone field. Numbers may or may not have a +.
- Numbers with or without a + are considered identical.

Comment: Can you split that PHONE_NUMBER columns in two: PREFIX and NUMBER?

Comment: The `+` sign doesnt occur in the middle of the string or does it ?? if it doesnt then just simply use a REPLACE function and replace `+`with an empty string `''` when joining two tables. Not the best option but if they are small table with not a lot of rows it will do the job.

Comment: @M.Ali would work even if `+` sign is in the middle of a string

Comment: @elite5472 my answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

You can go two ways

1. [`REPLACE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186862.aspx)
   `REPLACE(phone,'+','')`
2. if the length of numbers are constant - [`SUBSTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187748.aspx)
   `SUBSTRING(phone, (-1)*@length)`
   Where `@length` in the length of your number

So, the join will look like
`A JOIN B ON REPLACE(A.phone,'+','') = REPLACE(B.phone,'+','')`
 or
`A JOIN B ON SUBSTRING(A.phone, @length) = SUBSTRING(B.phone, @length)`

Comment: I can just put this in a join clause?

Comment: sure you can, why not?

Comment: Bear in mind that this will render any indexes on this column ineffective and degrade query performance.  But, sometimes it's what you have to do.

Comment: You can `JOIN` on any predicate, from simple ones like X = Y to complex ones like `REPLACE(X.phone, '+', '') = REPLACE(Y.phone, '+', '')`